# Homomorphism of vector bundle with connection

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

If one has two vector bundles $\pi : E \to M $ and $\pi' : E' \to M$ each one with a connection $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ ,how is a morphism of vector bundle with connection between them defined ? I wasn't able to find a unique definition

Comment: a smooth map $\varphi:E\rightarrow E'$ such that $\pi'\circ\varphi=\pi$

Comment: Ok, but the fact that I 've got connections on them should add some conditions on $\varphi$..

Comment: Do You mean something like $\nabla'_{X}\varphi(Y)=\nabla_{X}Y$?

Comment: Oh yes, it seems correct. Sry, it was rly easy.

Comment: Supposing $Y \in \Gamma(E)$, should this not be $\nabla'_X \varphi(Y) = \varphi(\nabla_X Y)$?